# Removendo objecto da ArrayList, o objecto continua lá

Tags: java

Eu e um amigo estamos criando um jogo no qual o personagem captura moedas e com isso ganha pontos. Eu criei um ArrayList de moedas e quando o retangulo do personagem intersecta com o retangulo da imagem da moeda a imagem desaparece.

***Nota: a imagem da moeda desaparece mas os pontos continuam a aumentar como se a imagem estivesse la.**
Este e' o meu codigo:

```
coinsList = new ArrayList<Item>();
coin = new Item(this, 100, 150);
coinsList.add(coin);

Rectangle rCoin = new Rectangle(coin.x, coin.y, coin.getWidth(), coin.getHeight());
    if(rCharacter.intersects(rCoin)) {
        coinsList.remove(coin);
        Points += 5;
```

Como consigo remover a moeda completamente e nao somente a imagem da mesma?

Comment: If you want the English version of SO go here: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). This is the Portuguese version and even if you ask there, you still have to provide more information or other parts of your code. As the error might not be in this part.

Comment: Eu pensava que estava na versão inglesa, peço desculpa.  Eu acho que o problema é com o rectângulo que continua naquela localização e daí continua a fazer a intercepção repetidamente mas não vejo maneira de remover o rectângulo. Que outras partes do código deveria mostrar?

Comment: Poderia postar a declaração da classe Rectangle?

Comment: A classe rectangle é um import do Java, eu não lhe fiz alterações.
import java.awt.Rectangle;

Answer (score 2):

#### Você deve sobrescrever o método equals()

Quando você faz:

```
coin = new Item(this, 100, 150);
```

você está criando um novo objeto. Logo, por mais que se tenha outro objeto com atributos idênticos no *heap* , eles continuam sendo objetos diferentes, entretanto com atributos iguais.

Você tenta passar um objeto **novo** para o método de remover da lista, consequentemente o objeto novo **não está** na lista, o que talvez tenha na lista é um **objeto diferente com atributos idênticos**.

De acordo com a documentação do java, sobre o método `remove()`:

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

Resumidamente, o `remove()` usa o resultado do método equals para dizer se os objetos são "iguais" ou não.

Portanto, você deve sobrescrever o método equals() para dizer quando objetos diferentes são considerados iguais.

As IDEs mais modernas todas já vem com a opção de sobrescrita do método equals automaticamente, então é bem fácil para fazer tal operação. Uma possível sobrescrita do método equals seria conforme a seguir:

```
public class Item {
    private Object GrupoItem;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Item other = (Item) obj;
        if (GrupoItem == null) {
            if (other.GrupoItem != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!GrupoItem.equals(other.GrupoItem))
            return false;
        if (height != other.height)
            return false;
        if (width != other.width)
            return false;
        return true;
    }    
}
```

O código eu gerei automaticamente pelo Eclipse. Nele o método equals compara atributo por atributo, se todos eles forem considerados iguais o método retorna *true*, caso ao menos um dos atributos for considerado diferente, o método retorna *false*.

Referência: [List - Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar dentro do `if`

`rCoin = null;`